# Android ListView scrollbar thumb size not handled correctly

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar, overscroll

To disable fast scroll on a desired touch behaviour, I'd like to have the same design for normal scroll an fast scroll on a listview. I took the fast scroll thumb and set it as normal scroll thumb, but there is a strange scrolling issue with the normal thumb.

On scrolling to the bottom, half of the thumb disappears behind the bottom line, the forced height of the thumb is ignored.

This is the thumb shape, I moved the offset to the top to have the thumb aligned to the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:top="-32dp" android:bottom="0dp">
      <shape>
        <size android:height="48dp" android:width="8dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#cbcbcb"/>
      </shape>
    </item>
  </layer-list>
```

This is what it shoud look like and what it's looks like if I scroll to the top, the blue marked shape is invisble behind the top panel, so the scrolling does not stop when the thumb reaches the top.

[image: thumb]

I tried to set an offset or padding but without success, it seems there is a fix physical height of the default thumb which can't be overwritten.